# How to make passport.js failureRedirect work with inline angular templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm making a MEAN reddit clone and currently working on authentication using Passport

I'm using ui-router as my angular routing module and the inline templating is giving me problems. Specifically, when I pass the {failureRedirect: "/signup" } object to the passport authentication route (included below, along with the angular module) it looks up and fails to find a view called "signup"

How can i successfully redirect it to another inline template (or, failing that, abstract the view into seperate files?

```
// Login form authentication
app.post("/login" 
    ,passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect : "/",
        failureRedirect : "/signup",
    })
);

//Angular
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                postPromise: ['postFactory', function (postFactory) {
                    return postFactory.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: '/login.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: '/signup.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: '/profile.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('new', {
            url: '/new',
            templateUrl: '/new.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
    .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: '/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl',
        resolve: {
    post: ['$stateParams', 'postFactory', function ($stateParams, postFactory) {
      return postFactory.get($stateParams.id);
    }]
  }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

Comment: Are you using HTML5 mode, did you try `/#!/signup`?

Comment: Yeah. Just gave it a shot, but it redirected me back to the home page.

Comment: Solved it. Trying it with just `/#/signup` worked swimmingly